# Split table value into multipe columns and create a column name as well

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

For a Database in SQL server, I have data for one column that looks like this

```
Severity
10006=0;10007=2;10008=5;10009=1;
10006=0;10007=1;10008=6;10009=0;
10006=0;10007=3;10008=5;10009=1;
```

- 10006 = Critical
- 10007 = Major
- 10008 = Minor
- 10009 = Trivial

Is there a way to create a function where I can select columnName. and have the output match this result.

```
critical  Major  Minor   Trivial
--------------------------------
0          2      5        1
0          1      6        0
0          3      5        1
```

Comment: Are you looking for split function? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=tsql+split+function

Answer (score 2):

This works for the data

```
with t as (
select '10006=0;10007=2;10008=5;10009=1;' as col union
select '10006=0;10007=1;10008=6;10009=0;' union
select '10006=0;10007=3;10008=5;10009=1;')

select substring(col,patindex('%10006=[0-9];%',col)+6,1) as critical,
       substring(col,patindex('%10007=[0-9];%',col)+6,1) as major,
       substring(col,patindex('%10008=[0-9];%',col)+6,1) as minor,
       substring(col,patindex('%10009=[0-9];%',col)+6,1) as trivial
from t
```

Comment: How would i change the code if the range is greater than 0-9?  For instance if 10007 = 23;  with t as (
select SeverityColumn as col from TableName)
select substring(col,patindex('%10006=[0-9];%',col)+6,1) as critical,
       substring(col,patindex('%10007=[0-9];%',col)+6,1) as major,
       substring(col,patindex('%10008=[0-9];%',col)+6,1) as minor,
       substring(col,patindex('%10009=[0-9];%',col)+6,1) as trivial
from t        Thanks for your help